# How can I make cell formatting to not repeat myself?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code, where I apply the same rules for more than two elements:

```
activities.forEach((act) => {
    mainSheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex)
    .setValue(act.text)
    .setFontStyle('italic')
    .setFontFamily('Verdana')
    .setFontSize(12)
    .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, act.color, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)

  mainSheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex + 2)
    .setFontStyle('italic')
    .setFontFamily('Verdana')
    .setFontSize(10)
    .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, act.color, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)

    rowIndex += 2;
  })
```

I repeat:

FontStyle

FontFamily

setBorder

Any suggestions on how I can make it neater?

I would like to use copy format in Google Sheets, but I don't want to make a cell for it. Maybe it's possible to create a not existing cell, so I can write my formatting there and then apply it to my elements?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and specify your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value and format of all cells with one call by creating a `RangeList` object. To create the `RangeList` object, use `Array.map()` or another `Array` method to collect the ranges, like this:

```
  const rowNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12,];
  const columnLabels = ['C', 'E'];
  const rangeList = rowNumbers.map(row => columnLabels.map(col => col + row));
  mainSheet.getRangeList(rangeList)
    .setValue(act.text)
    .setFontStyle('italic')
    .setFontFamily('Verdana')
    .setFontSize(12)
    .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, act.color, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
```

It is unclear why you are looping over `activities.forEach()` if your intention is to use the same format with all cells. If you want to only set the *value* in some of the cells and not all of them, create another `RangeList` object and call its `.setValue()` method.